# Is there any plugin for MODX for managing the item tree in a wordpress style? with pagination and etc?

Tags: plugins, tree, modx, extras

Some clients complain about how messy it is to manage a site with lots of blog posts thru the item tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for here is probably the [Articles extra](http://modx.com/extras/package/articles/) by Shaun McCormick.

It is meant to be a tool for easy blogging and brings a Custom Manager Page with an overview over all articles it manages while excluding them from the tree. It even comes with an option to import posts from Wordpress blogs or from existing resources. If you don't need the blogging features like comments etc., you can just unset them. You will need MODX version >= 2.2 to use it.

[image: Articles CMP Screenshot]